# How do I properly ask (or search google) for help aggregating objects from different db models?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to list objects from two different mongoDB database models on the same index page. Right now I have them split on two different index pages because I didn't think this through ahead of time.

The problem is I don't even know how to search the request above on google or within the bootstrap docs (I'm using bootstrap on the front end). I keep getting different "modals" instead of models and I'm at the end of my programming vocabulary (it's *very* limited).

Can you help me reword my question in the correct terminology, please?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking about the MongoDB aggregation pipeline. This is a server feature and if you haven't already, you should at least read [this page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#:%7E:text=The%20aggregation%20pipeline%20is%20a%20framework%20for%20data,pipeline%20that%20transforms%20the%20documents%20into%20aggregated%20results.) to get a basic understanding of what it is from the server's standpoint.

Next, if you haven't done this already, you should install `mongo` shell and get it working on your machine, and try executing some simple operations (such as an insert and a find), after which you should run the various aggregation examples in the mongo shell to familiarize yourself with the feature.

After this, review your MongoDB driver documentation for how to work with the aggregation pipeline. For Ruby driver for example, this is [documented here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-aggregation/). You'll note that the syntax is different from the mongo shell examples. If you are using node.js, the syntax will also be different from mongo shell examples even though both your driver and mongo shell use javascript.

If you aren't using a driver directly but are using a  higher level library such as an ODM (e.g. Mongoose), there may be yet another way of executing aggregation with its own syntax provided by that library. You may not need to know how driver aggregation works if you are using an ODM, but you may find that the ODM doesn't implement some feature that the driver implements (and MongoDB documentation references).

The reason why I suggest doing all of this is that when you are constructing aggregation pipelines, you almost always need to do so as the aggregation pipeline stages, operators and expressions are documented for the server, even if you are using a much higher level library to execute the aggregation or generally interact with your database.

Once you understand how the aggregation pipelines are executed and how to construct them, use your application schema to construct the appropriate queries. There generally isn't comprehensive documentation for aggregation pipeline beyond the official MongoDB docs, due to the size of the aggregation pipeline as a feature. You are generally on your own as far as actually constructing the pipelines for your application in the language/framework that you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the super comprehensive answer. I read through the material and watched some videos and this appears to be more for data analysis. Apologies, I think this is where the limited scope of my vocabulary gets me in trouble, but I'm looking to display the objects from my two different mongoDB models on one page (in aggregate).

I already have the mongo shell and mongoose setup -- my two (structured) db models are populated and displaying on separate web pages in my app. I just don't know how to pull them into the same page. Would that still be through the aggregation pipeline?

Comment: Aggregation pipeline allows you to retrieve data from multiple collections in one server query. You can get the same data without the aggregation pipeline in many cases by making multiple queries, generally this is less efficient but may be simpler to implement.